# iOS XCode capabilities are missing in the build

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, appsflyer

I am currently working on an ionic app. and using deep links(appsflyer) in my project. So when i build for iOS i turned on the associated domains and added the domain.
but when i upload it to test flight and check, under device requirements-> required capabilities are missing.
what could be the reason?

Comment: This problem solved after adding release entitlements manually. And also you have to check the automatic sign in in the general tab